# How to migrate AWS Elasticsearch to Azure Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-elasticsearch

Is there any procedure or documentation supported by Microsoft in order to migrate AWS Elasticsearch to Azure Elasticsearch? Do anyone knows the process to do so?

Comment: does Azure offer ElasticSearch as a service ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any information by Microsoft about it, but our AWS Elasticsearch Service supports manual snapshots, that you can store on S3 and can then use to restore a cluster elsewhere.

The people from Alibaba Cloud have a [step-by-step post](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/72927.htm) of how to migrate from AWS to their cloud, so you can take that as a starting point.

Comment: Well we are looking specificaly for Azure, is there any supported way of doing this?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know much about Azure. From AWS point of view you have the snapshot as the general export mechanism